# Standard documentation of Visual Studio commands?

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, command

Visual Studio has a concept of commands, i.e. actions executable by pressing a shortcut, entering them on the Command Window etc.

Visual Studio itself documents its commands (at least [some of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c338aexd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) but I was wondering if there is a unified way to get information about any command, e.g. coming from ReSharper, TestDriven.NET etc. What I'd like to see for every command:

- Textual description of the command
- List of parameters and their types/allowed values

I've never developed a VS addon / extension so am not sure if this question even makes sense but from the user perspective, some documentation would be greatly appreciated.

**BTW**, is the Command Window the best place to get at least an overview of all the commands available? Tools>Options>Keyboard is another place where I can see shortcuts also but the UI is not very convenient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that command's `Name` is the only "documentation" available for it - no support for additional metadata, unfortunately.